# Azure Media Service video encode with rotation

Tags: azure-media-services

I have videos recorded with phone in portrait and need to encode them with 90, -90 or 180 degree rotation.

Encoding presets doesn't seem to have this option.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj129582.aspx

How to define encoding rotation for video asset?

**Edit**:

Got answer from Media Services forum. Its not supported at moment.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MediaServices/thread/68090985-b1ad-4d52-bb08-c4386654c1b9

Comment: Just going back and checking old messages - this is supported now.